# setState return undefined in Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I was trying to make a component that by Clicking outside a specific ref will hide that ref. while using **setState to boolean value false it return undefined**.

**useOnclick Hook:**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function useOnClickOutside(ref, Cb, event) {
    
    const handler = (e) => {
        if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
            Cb()
        }
      };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (event) {
            document.addEventListener("click", handler);
            return () => {document.removeEventListener("click", handler)}
        }
      }, [event]);
}
```

**Component**

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import styles from 'assets/css/DropDown1.module.css'
import useOnClickOutside from 'hooks/useOnClickOutside'

export default function DropDown1() {
    const [Display, setDisplay] = useState(false)
    const [Text, setText] = useState('Choose Option')

    const modalref = useRef()

    useOnClickOutside(modalref, ()=>setDisplay(false), Display)
    
  return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <section className={styles.wraper}>
              <div className={styles.header}>
                  <h4 className={styles.toogler_heading}>{Text}</h4>
                  <button className={styles.icon} onClick={()=> setDisplay(!Display)}>Click</button>

                  {Display ?
                      <div className={styles.dropdown_menu} ref={modalref}>
                        <ul className={styles.dropdown_wraper} onClick={() => setDisplay(false)}>
                            <li onClick={(e) => (setText(e.currentTarget.textContent))}>
                                First
                            </li>
                            <li onClick={(e) => (setText(e.currentTarget.textContent))}>
                                Second
                            </li>
                            <li onClick={(e) => (setText(e.currentTarget.textContent))}>
                                Third
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                      </div> : null}
              </div>
        </section>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

On clicking `<button className={styles.icon} onClick={()=> setDisplay(!Display)}>Click</button>`  undefined is returned inside console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the handler in useOnClickOutside catches every click on the click button. After click button has set Display to true, the handler sets it back to false. Change the handler function like this:

```
const handler = (e) => {
  if (ref.current && !Display && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
    Cb()
  }
};
```